# Iterate in reverse through an array with PHP - SPL solution?

Tags: php, reverse, loops, spl

Is there an SPL Reverse array iterator in PHP?
And if not, what would be the best way to achieve it?

I could simply do

```
$array = array_reverse($array);
foreach($array as $currentElement) {}
```

or

```
for($i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{

}
```

But is there a more elegant way?

Comment: your second method is not necessarily right. only works for numeric consequential keys

Comment: Woops, yeah, that's true. In my case I have a numerical array, but your comment makes my question even more relevant I think.

Comment: numerical array are not necessarily sequential in order, and do not necessarily start from 0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no `ReverseArrayIterator` to do that. You can do

```
$reverted = new ArrayIterator(array_reverse($data));
```

or make that into your own custom iterator, e.g.

```
class ReverseArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator 
{
    public function __construct(array $array)
    {
        parent::__construct(array_reverse($array));
    }
}
```

A slightly longer implementation that doesn't use `array_reverse` but iterates the array via the standard array functions would be

```
class ReverseArrayIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $array;

    public function __construct(array $array)
    {
        $this->array = $array;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->array);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return prev($this->array);
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->array);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return key($this->array) !== null;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        end($this->array);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to do array_reverse($array, true) in order to preserve key association for numeric keys.

Comment: Keep in mind that array_reverse copies array elements, hence not very performance wise

Comment: array_reverse is expensive, I wouldn't recommend doing that every time you need to iterate. better to store things in reverse order from the start or use @linepogl's solution.

Comment: Not elegant reversing the whole array, this reply does't actually change anything from the OP solutions, just added syntactic sugar (and even more overhead) to the original.

Comment: @FrancescoMM no one asked for an elegant solution. And while it doesn't add much over the procedural approach, the OP specifically asked for an SPL iterator.

Comment: "But is there a more elegant way?", cit. the OP

Comment: @FrancescoMM I stand corrected. Still, I feel the emphasis should be on iterator and SPL and not on elegant, which is why I provided an additional iterator above.

Comment: @Gordon yes but array_reverse is so inefficient on long arrays, using yield or iterating in reverse would be "logically speaking" more correct, I think

Answer (score 78):

Here is a solution that does not copy and does not modify the array:

```
for (end($array); key($array)!==null; prev($array)){
  $currentElement = current($array);
  // ...
}
```

If you also want a reference to the current key:

```
for (end($array); ($currentKey=key($array))!==null; prev($array)){
  $currentElement = current($array);
  // ...
}
```

This works always as php array keys can never be null and is faster than any other answer given here.

Comment: Best answer here. Thank you!

Comment: This is a correct solution for traversing an array, getting any key (numeric or not) and value (including nulls) in reverse order.

Comment: The OP asked for an iterator though.

Comment: But PHP only supports "internal" iterator currently (hence the answer to OP is "impossible"), but that should be no problem, unless the internal iterator is changed (by something inside the loop) unintentionally.

Comment: However that still modifies the array, does it not? It changes the internal array pointer. For the record regular `foreach` also changes the internal pointer.

Answer (score 17):

```
$item=end($array);
do {
...
} while ($item=prev($array));
```

Comment: end sets the internal array iterator to the last element and returns it. prev returns the current element and set iterator to the previous one.

Comment: Actually, the second version will skip the very last element of the array.

Comment: Down voting. The second version skips the last element.

Comment: what if one of the array's values is false or NULL or 0 ?

Answer (score 12):

Based on [linepogl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25769831/65387), I came up with this function:

```
/**
 * Iterate an array or other foreach-able without making a copy of it.
 *
 * @param array|\Traversable $iterable
 * @return Generator
 */
function iter_reverse($iterable) {
    for (end($iterable); ($key=key($iterable))!==null; prev($iterable)){
        yield $key => current($iterable);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach(iter_reverse($my_array) as $key => $value) {
    // ... do things ...
}
```

This works on arrays and other iterables without first making a copy of it.

Comment: Nice, it can even be optimized using [C.M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315539/iterate-in-reverse-through-an-array-with-php-spl-solution/48407440#48407440) to avoid the `current()` call.

Comment: Note that because inside the function we are altering the internal pointer, while PHP ensures it doesn't affect the pointer of the array outside the function, it actually creates a copy of the array.

Comment: With the exception of `end()`, the other two functions have been deprecated from working with objects: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php#refsect1-function.key-changelog, too bad.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to look into the spl data structure classes, such as SplStack. SplStack implements Iterator, ArrayAccess and Countable, so it can mostly be used like an array, but by default, its iterator proceeds in FILO order. Ex:

```
$stack = new SplStack();
$stack[] = 'one';
$stack[] = 'two';
$stack[] = 'three';

foreach ($stack as $item)
{
    print "$item\n";
}
```

This will print

```
three
two
one
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that if you want to preserve the keys of the array, you must pass `true` as the second parameter to `array_reverse`:

```
$array = array_reverse($array, true);
foreach ($array as $currentElement) {
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on *linepogl's* answer... You can make it even more efficient by avoiding `current()` call

```
for ($value = end($array); ($key = key($array)) !== null; $value = prev($array)) {
     // ... do something with $key => $value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = array_reverse($array);
foreach($array as $key => $currentElement) {}
```

This is better way to use. It will take care of keys also, if they are not sequential or integer.

Comment: This can be shortened to just `foreach(array_reverse($array, true) ...` if you don't need to keep the reversed array.  Keep in mind the second argument to `array_reverse`, which keeps the keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array=array(
    0 => 0,
    '1' => 1,
    2 => null,
    3 => false
);

$value=end( $array );                      // ← value for first iteration
while(($key=key( $array )) !== null) {
  echo "key=$key, value=$value\n";

  $value=prev( $array );                   // ← value for next iteration
}
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely helpful. Please consider adding some context to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a more performant way since it doesnt construct a new array. It also handles empty arrays well.

```
$item = end($items);
while($item)
{
    ...do stuff...
    $item = prev($items);
}
```

Comment: what if one of the items' values is false or NULL or 0 ?

Answer (score -2):

$array1= array(10,20,30,40,50);

```
        for($i = count($array1) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
        {
            $array2[]  = $array1[$i];

        }

        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($array2);
        echo "</pre>";
```