# How do I set the foreach loop to start at the last array?

Tags: php, foreach

How do I set my foreach loop to start looking at the last entry of the array then each loop will go backwards instead of forward?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315539/iterate-in-reverse-through-an-array-with-php-spl-solution

Answer (score 10):

You could just [reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) the array:

```
$reverse = array_reverse($array, true); // true to preserve keys
foreach($reverse as $key => $value) { /* etc. */ }
```

Or if you're sure that the array contains only numeric keys, this is probably faster:

```
for($i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  /* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(array_reverse($array, true) as $key=>$value)
```

The array_reverse function will reverse an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$values = array();
$max = count($values);

foreach($i = $max; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $key = $values[$i];
    // do something with the key
}
```