# Iterate array from the end without reverse

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following array in PHP:

```
$a = ['2015-10-10'=>'30', '2015-11-11'=>'100'];
```

How do I iterate through the array from the end without reversing it first. I want to check and change all of the values based on conditions.

Comment: you mean a for loop with `i--` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate in reverse through an array with PHP - SPL solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315539/iterate-in-reverse-through-an-array-with-php-spl-solution)

Comment: @andrew, sorry if it's not clear enough. so, inside the loop I will change the value, eg. `$a['2015-11-11'] = '233'`.. can `i--` do that?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta: thanks, but I cannot use array_reverse since it will take effect to the rest of my code.

Comment: @DarielPratama at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315539/iterate-in-reverse-through-an-array-with-php-spl-solution some solution do not have `array_reverse`

Comment: @DarielPratama check out the second answer from the post above. or you can use see in the answer below.

Comment: oh yes, sorry my bad..thanks chetan and andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$new_array=end($a);

do {
    // Your Code here
}
while ($new_array=prev($a));
```

Answer (score 0):

the above answer  will results an error if one of the array's values is false or NULL or 0 , try this you will get an new idea

```
<?php
$a = array('2015-10-10'=>'30', '2015-11-11'=>'100', '2015-14-11'=>'105');
$im=implode(',', $a);// make as a string 
$newarr=explode(',',$im);// convert it as an array with 0-3 as a index
$size=sizeof($newarr);
$size=sizeof($newarr);
for($j=$size;$j>=0;$j--){// reverse loop
echo $newarr[$j]."<br>";
}
//print_r($newarr);
//print_r($im);
?>
```